# How to delete specific rows from multiple columns

Tags: r, csv

I am importing some columns from multiple csv files from R. I want to delete all the data after row 1472.

```
temp = list.files(pattern="*.csv")    #Importing csv files
Normalyears<-c(temp[1],temp[2],temp[3],temp[5],temp[6],temp[7],temp[9],temp[10],temp[11],temp[13],temp[14],temp[15],temp[17],temp[18],temp[19],temp[21],temp[22],temp[23])
leapyears<-c(temp[4],temp[8],temp[12],temp[16],temp[20])      #separating csv files with based on leap years and normal years.

Importing only the second column of each csv file.

myfiles_Normalyears = lapply(Normalyears, read.delim,colClasses=c('NULL','numeric'),sep =",")
myfiles_leapyears = lapply(leapyears, read.delim,colClasses=c('NULL','numeric'),sep =",")

new.data.leapyears <- NULL

for(i in 1:length(myfiles_leapyears)) { 
 in.data <-      read.table(if(is.null(myfiles_leapyears[i])),skip=c(1472:4399),sep=",")
 new.data.leapyears <- rbind(new.data.leapyears, in.data)}
```

the loop is suppose to delete all the rows starting from 1472 to 4399.

```
  Error: Error in read.table(myfiles_leapyears[i], skip = c(1472:4399), sep = ",") :
```

'file' must be a character string or connection

Comment: is `myfiles_leapyears[i]` a string or a connection? You sure that's not where the error is? Actually look closer at your code, why do you have the `if` in the read.table call like that? Can you also make it reproducible?

Comment: There is no way, I can upload csv files here. Also, even when I get rid of "if" statement, the error is the following: Error in myfiles_leapyears[i] : invalid subscript type 'list'

Comment: You don't have to upload all of the csv's. Please see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `myfiles_leapyears` is a `list`. When subsetting a list, you need double brackets to access a single element, otherwise you just get a sublist of length 1.

So replace

```
myfiles_leapyears[i]
```

with

```
myfiles_leapyears[[i]]
```

that will at least take care of `invalid subscript type 'list'` errors. I'd second Josh W. that the `nrows` argument seems smarter than the `skip` argument.

Alternatively, if you define using `sapply` ("s" for simplify) instead of `lapply` ("l" for list), you'll probably be fine using `[i]`:

```
myfiles_leapyears = lapply(leapyears, read.delim,colClasses=c('NULL','numeric'),sep =",")
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a `nrows` parameter to `read.table`, so why not try

`read.table(myfiles_leapyears[i], nrows = 1471,sep=",")`

Comment: nope, here is the error: Error in myfiles_leapyears[i] : invalid subscript type 'list'

Comment: try `myfiles_leapyears[[i]]`

Comment: No matter what, the error persists Error:  'file' must be a character string or connection

Comment: What is the output of `str(myfiles_leapyears)` ?

Answer (score 0):

It is fine. I just turned the data from a list into a dataframe.

```
     df <- as.data.frame(myfiles_leapyears,byrow=T)

     leap_df<-head(df,-2928)
```